# c# Как сделать select key - field?

Tags: c#, select

Есть модель данных:

```
public class Item1
{
    public long Addr { get; set; }
    public long Pos { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    public long Addr { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ulong Pointer{ get; set; }
}
```

Создается items1 и Item2:

```
var items1 = new Dictionary<ulong, Item1>();
items1.Add(id, new Item1
{
    Addr = Addr,
    Pos = Pos,
    Description = Description,
    Number = Number
    Pointer = Pointer
});

var items2 = new Dictionary<ulong, Item2>();
items1.Add(id, new Item2
{
    Addr = Addr,
    Description = Description,
    Pointer = Pointer
});
```

Есть список **itemPointers**, который содержит в себе совпадающие **id** в **items1** и **Pointer** в **item2**

> List itemPointers = new();

Как создать такой список **itemPointers**?

Пробовал играться с **itemPointers = items1.Select(e =>items2.ContainsKey(e.Pointer))**, понимаю что где то в items2.ContainsKey(e.Pointer) должен быть ForEach, но не могу понять где
Знаю, что можно сделать так

```
foreach (var id in items2)
{
    if (items1.ContainsKey(items2[id.Key].Pointer))
    {
        itemPointers.Add(id.Key);
    }
}
```

Но кажется есть более элегантный(быстрый?) способ это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код почти нормальный, но если хочется, можно так:

```
ulong[] itemPointers = items2
    .Where(pair => items1.ContainsKey(pair.Value.Pointer))
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

А вообще в вашем коде просто можно заменить `items2[id.Key].Pointer` на `id.Value.Pointer` и будет норм.

Переименуйте `id` в `pair` так как это пара ключ-значение, код лучше читаться будет. Классы `Item1` и `Item2` тоже можно переименовать во что-то более человекочитаемое.

---

*Если возникает случай где без разницы что использовать, список или массив, всегда выбирайте массив. Он более легковесный и код работы с массивами подлежит более серьёзным оптимизациям во время компиляции, чем со списками.*

Comment: Спасибо! Использование списков обусловлено легким доступом по ключу без итераций (в моем понимании), в случае с массивами было бы очень много циклов поиска (в разных местах кода нужно постоянно что да искать) или их кол-во не сильно влияет и может действительно проще делать итерации для поиска нужного объекта с точки зрения оптимизации?
П.с фантазия называть объекты в коде для вопроса скудная)

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov в плане доступа к элементам между списком и массивом разницы нет. Вы со словарями не путайте.

Comment: а, ну да, не так прочел, спасибо)

Comment: не совсем по теме, но не думаю что это тянет на вопрос в SO, будет ли правильно кэшировать разные посчитанные данные с указателями в виде ключа из подобных словарей используя `var cached = new Dictionary<ulong, Item1>();`? Имеется ввиду сам метод хранения и отдавания при налчии

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov вы разработчик, вам и решать. :)

Comment: проблема в том, что я пытаюсь мыслить логически и для меня это самый логичный вариант, о других я попросту не знаю :D

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov пробовать никто не запрещает. Делайте как умеете, переписать всегда можно успеть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137835/discussion-between-anton-kuznetsov-and-aepot).